# How do I change an element in a parent class into an attribute in a derived class with JAXB annotations?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, annotations

I want an XML element to look like this:

```
<xmlObject id="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" />
```

I've got a situation where I need to marshal an object. My base object looks like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    private UUID id;
    public UUID getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(UUID value) { id = value; }
}
```

I want to have the id as an attribute of the object rather than an element, but I don't want to do it in the `MyObject`, since I feel that the class shouldn't need to know how to represent itself in XML. I have the following class that is meant to do the whole 'id as an attribute' magic; I also represent the object as an element called 'xmlObject':

```
@XmlRootElement("xmlObject")
public class MyXmlObject extends MyObject {
    @Override
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public void setId(UUID value) { id = value; }
}
```

This attempt was *somewhat* successful, as can bee seen in the results below:

```
<xmlObject id="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111">
    <id>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</id>
</xmlObject>
```

The id is now an attribute, but it's ALSO still an element! I tried to get rid of the element by adding the `XmlAccessorType` annotation to only allow JAXB to recognize annotated fields/properties, but that didn't work as the id was still written as an element:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement("xmlObject")
public class MyXmlObject ...
```

If I place the annotation on the parent class (`MyObject`) then the id is no longer an element, but as I mentioned earlierr I wish to avoid placing the annotation on `MyObject`. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you want, you may use wrapper to not annotate your main object.

An example.

*Main Object you do not want to annotate:*

```
public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String userSurname;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserSurname() {
        return userSurname;
    }

    public void setUserSurname(String userSurname) {
        this.userSurname = userSurname;
    }

}
```

*Wrapper object which will be annotated:*

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xmlUser")
class UserWrapper {

    private User user;

    public UserWrapper() {
    }

    public UserWrapper(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return user.getUserName();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "surname")
    public String getUserSurname() {
        return user.getUserSurname();
    }

}
```

The only thing here is you have to kinda override your getters from main object, which you want to be annotated.

Marshaller example:

```
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName("Name");
        user.setUserSurname("Surname");

        UserWrapper userWrapper = new UserWrapper(user);

        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(userWrapper, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As a result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xmlUser name="Name">
    <surname>Surname</surname>
</xmlUser>
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered simply wrapping the object. I'll give this a try and see how it goes.